# Flutter: How can I Navigate to new screen in Persistent Bottom Navigation Bar package

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) package. Can anyone please tell me how can I use

`Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context)` rather than using a `pushNewScreen()`. This is mainly because I want to reload the entire screen whenever user chooses a new bottom item. I am guessing that `pushNewScreen()` does not pop the old screen and just adds it on the stack.

**Persisten Navigation Bar code:**

```
PersistentTabView(
context,
backgroundColor: darkThemeColour,
confineInSafeArea: true,
screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation(
  // Screen transition animation on change of selected tab.
  animateTabTransition: true,
  curve: Curves.ease,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
),
// context: context,
navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style12,
controller: _controller,
items: [
  PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
    activeColorPrimary: iconColour,
    inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
    inactiveIcon: Icon(
      Icons.home_outlined,
      size: iconSize,
    ),
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.home,
      size: iconSize,
    ),
    routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
      // initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        RestaurantOverview.routeName: (context) => RestaurantOverview(),
        // RestaurantDetailsScreen.routeName: (context) =>
        //     RestaurantDetailsScreen(),
      },
    ),
  ),
  PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
    activeColorPrimary: iconColour,
    inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
    inactiveIcon: Icon(
      Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
      size: iconSize,
    ),
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.shopping_cart,
      size: iconSize,
    ),
    routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
      // initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        MealCartScreen.routeName: (context) => MealCartScreen(),
        // CartDetailsScreen.routeName: (context) => CartDetailsScreen(),
      },
    ),
  ),
  PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
    activeColorPrimary: iconColour,
    inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
    inactiveIcon: Icon(
      Icons.account_circle_outlined,
      size: iconSize,
    ),
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.account_circle_rounded,
      size: iconSize,
    ),
    routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
      // initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/first': (context) => OrderScreen(),
      },
    ),
  ),
],
screens: [
  RestaurantOverview(),
  // RestaurantDetailsScreen(),
  MealCartScreen(),
  // CartDetailsScreen(),
  OrderScreen(),
],
);
```

**pushNewScreen code:**

```
pushNewScreen(
  context,
  screen: CartDetailsScreen(cartItems[i]),
  withNavBar: true,
);
```

Please can someone help me with this

Answer (score 2):

There is a option in the PersistenTabView called *stateManagement*, set it to false. That will do the trick.

```
return PersistentTabView(
      ...
      stateManagement: false,
      ...
)
```